# Не сохраняются картинки на компьюторе

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста. Это файл обработки картинок. Когда нажимаю сохранить то картинки в БД добавляются, а на компьютер в папку avatars не добавляется. В связи этим не отображается аватарка. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
<?php
session_start(); // сессия
// проверяем - запрос пришел при авторизованной сессии или нет?
if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'yes_auth') {
if (isset($_FILES['fupload']['name'])){ //отправлялась ли переменная
if (empty($_FILES['fupload']['name']) AND $_FILES['fupload']['name'] == ''){      
$noAvatar = "avatar.png";//изображение если пользователь не загрузил свое
$result = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM reg_user WHERE login='$login'");//извлекаем текущий аватар
$avatarka = mysql_fetch_array($result);      
if ($avatarka['avatar'] != $noAvatar) {//если аватар был стандартный, то не удаляем его, ведь у на одна картинка на всех.
unlink ('../avatars/'.$avatarka['avatar']);
}       
}
else{
//иначе - загружаем изображение пользователя для обновления
$path_to_90_directory = '../avatars/';//папка, куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия       
if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload']['name']))//проверка формата исходного изображения
{          
$filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
$source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']; 
$target = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($source, $target);//загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory
if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
$im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ;//если оригинал был в формате png
}       
if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory.$filename); //если оригинал был в формате jpg
}       
//СОЗДАНИЕ КВАДРАТНОГО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ И ЕГО ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЖАТИЕ      
$w = 150;  // ширина изображения      
$quality = 147; //Качество создаваемого изображения max 100        
$w_src = imagesx($im); //вычисляем ширину
$h_src = imagesy($im); //вычисляем высоту изображения      
//Создавать квадратное изображение $rezim = 1
//Создать изображение пропорционально оригиналу $rezim = 2      
$rezim = 1;       
switch ($rezim){
//**************************** 1
case "1" :         
// создаём пустую квадратную картинку 
// важно именно truecolor!, иначе будем иметь 8-битный результат 
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$w); 
// вырезаем квадратную серединку по x, если фото горизонтальное          
if ($w_src > $h_src){ 
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, round((max($w_src,$h_src)-min($w_src,$h_src))/2), 0, $w, $w, min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src));
}
// вырезаем квадратную верхушку по y, 
if ($w_src < $h_src){
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src)); 
}
// квадратная картинка масштабируется без вырезок     
if ($w_src == $h_src){
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, $w_src, $h_src); 
}
break;
//***************************** 2
case "2" : 
$prop = $w_src/$h_src;
$h = $w/$prop;
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h); 
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_src, $h_src); 
break;   
}            
$random = rand(1000000, 9999999);
imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory.$random.".jpg", $quality);//сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку  
$avatar = $random.".jpg";//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.
$delfull = $path_to_90_directory.$filename; 
unlink ($delfull);//удаляем оригинал загруженного изображения, он нам больше не нужен.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM reg_user WHERE login='$login'");//извлекаем текущий аватар пользователя
$avatarka = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($avatarka['avatar'] != $noAvatar) {//если аватар был стандартный, то не удаляем его, ведь у на одна картинка на всех.
unlink ('../avatars/'.$avatarka['avatar']);
}
}
else{
//в случае несоответствия формата, выдаем соответствующее сообщение
exit ("Аватар должен быть в формате <strong>JPG или PNG</strong>");
}  
}
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE reg_user SET avatar='$avatar' WHERE login='$login'");//обновляем аватар в базе
if ($up == true) {//если верно, то отправляем на личную страничку
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=profile.php?login=".$login."'>";
}
}
} else
die("Авторизуйтесь или зарегистрируйтесь");
?>
```

```html
<form method="post"> 
<?php 
echo "<img src='avatars/".$avatar."'> <br><br>";            
?>
<table width="600" border="0">
<tr>
<td> Изменить аватар </td>
<td>
<form action='include/save_avatar.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" name="fupload" id="fupload" size='8'>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>     
<ul id="info-profile">

<li>
<label for="info_surname">Фамилия</label>
<span class="star"></span>
<input type="text" name="info_surname" id="info_surname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['auth_surname']; ?>"  />
</li>
//дальше имя телефон и так далее
<p align="right"><input type="submit" id="form_submit2" name="save_submit2" value="Сохранить" /></p>
<form>
```

У меня одна кнопка submit отвечающая за весь профиль

Comment: Еще добавь HTML формы. Сейчас исправим)

Comment: право записи в папку проверьте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В зависимости от `input type='file'`.

Как я понял, есть возможность выбрать только 1 файл для загрузки.
По этому пример делаю именно для одного файла. Переписал заново,
чуть изменил названия переменных и кое-что необходимое добавил.

Еще проверь аттрибут формы: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, добавь если нету.

```
$uploadFolder = Папка в которую грузят аватарки
$fileArray = это твой глобальный массив $_FILES['fupload'];
$defaultAvatar = Стандартная аватарка
$newAvatar = Новая аватарка, которая прошла все процедуры
$AllowedExtensions = допустимые расширения загружаемых файлов
$imageFormat = формат изображения для `imagecreatefrompng` или `imagecreatefromjpeg`
$maxSize = Максимальный размер загружаемого файла
$error = Массив ошибок который возвращается в случае несоответствия необходимым условиям
```

Проверки:

1. Авторизован ли пользователь
2. Выбран ли файл. Если не выбран, возвращает код ошибки 4
3. Проверяет MIME тип изображения. Ты проверял через название файла, так не годится.
4. Проверяет размер файла. Можешь себе его изменить, но вряд ли на хостинге разрешают размер больше.\
5. Если в массиве $error что-то есть, возвращает массив. Может его себе потом распечатать (print_r)
6. Проверяем загружен ли временный файл, если да, то продолжаем операции
7. Проверяем существует ли папка для загрузки аватаров
8. Перемещаем загруженый файл
9. После всех уменьшений и всё такое, проверяем наличие нового изображения в папке
10. Выбираем из БД название старого аватара и пытаемся удалить
11. Если по какой-то причине нет имени нового аватара, будет установлен стандартный
12. Если всё прошло успешно, пишем что мы молодцы, аватарка загружени.Пляшем и танцуем.

***Теперь сам код***

```
function updateUserAvatar($login) {

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db_name") or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $uploadFolder      = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/avatars/';
    $fileArray         = $_FILES['fupload'];
    $defaultAvatar     = 'avatar.png';
    $newAvatar         = NULL;
    $AllowedExtensions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
    $imageFormat       = '';
    $maxSize           = 1024 * 1024 * 15;
    $error             = [];

// Проверка 1
    if (!isset($_SESSION['auth']) && $_SESSION['auth'] != 'yes_auth')
        $error[] = 'Пройдите авторизацию чтобы изменить аватар';

// Проверка 2
    if ($fileArray['error'] == 4)
        $error[] = 'Вы не выбрали изображение для загрузки';

// Проверка 3
    if ($fileArray['tmp_name']) {
        $info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); //открываем изображение
        if (!in_array(finfo_file($info, $fileArray['tmp_name']), $AllowedExtensions))
            $error[] = "Допустимый формат изображения: JPG, JPEG, PNG";
        else
            $imageFormat = finfo_file($info, $fileArray['tmp_name']);
        if ($imageFormat == 'image/jpeg') $imageFormat = 'jpeg';
        else $imageFormat = 'png';
        finfo_close($info);
    }

// Проверка 4
    if ($fileArray['size'] > $maxSize)
        $error[] = "Максимальный размер файла: 15MB";

// Проверка 5
    if ($error) {
        return $error;
    } else {
// Проверка 6
    if (is_uploaded_file($fileArray['tmp_name'])) {
        $extension         = explode('.', $fileArray['name']);
        $extension         = '.' . end($extension);
        $fileArray['name'] = md5(rand(10, 99) . time() . $fileArray['name']) . $extension;
        $filePath          = $uploadFolder . $fileArray['name'];

// Проверка 7
        if (!file_exists($uploadFolder)) mkdir($uploadFolder, 0777, true);

// Проверка 8
        if (move_uploaded_file($fileArray['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
            $im               = NULL;
            $destinationImage = NULL;

            if ($imageFormat == 'png') $im = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
            if ($imageFormat == 'jpeg') $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);

            $width_original  = imagesx($im); //Ширину оригинала
            $height_original = imagesy($im); //Высота оригинала
            $width_new       = 150;  //Ширина нового изображения
            $quality         = 147; //Качество нового изображения max 100

            $resizeForm = 1; //1 - Квадратное изображение; 2 - Пропорционально оригиналу;
            switch ($resizeForm):
                case 1:
                    $destinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width_new, $width_new);

                    if ($width_original > $height_original)
                        imagecopyresampled($destinationImage, $im, 0, 0,
                                           round((max($width_original, $height_original) - min($width_original, $height_original)) / 2),
                                           0, $width_new, $width_new,
                                           min($width_original, $height_original), min($width_original, $height_original));

                    if ($width_original < $height_original)
                        imagecopyresampled($destinationImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_new, $width_new,
                                           min($width_original, $height_original), min($width_original, $height_original));

                    if ($width_original == $height_original)
                        imagecopyresampled($destinationImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_new, $width_new, $width_original, $height_original);

                break;

                case 2:
                    $prop             = $width_original / $height_original;
                    $height_new       = $width_new / $prop;
                    $destinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width_new, $height_new);
                    imagecopyresampled($destinationImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_new, $height_new, $width_original, $height_original);
                break;
            endswitch;

            $resizeFileName = md5(time() . (rand(1, 30) + rand(31, 62))) . '.jpg';
            $resizeFilePath = $uploadFolder . $resizeFileName;
            imagejpeg($destinationImage, $resizeFilePath, $quality);

// Проверка 9
            if (file_exists($resizeFilePath)) {
                unlink($filePath);
                $newAvatar = $resizeFileName;

// Проверка 10
                $oldAvatarDelete = "SELECT avatar FROM reg_user WHERE login = '$login' LIMIT 1";
                $oldAvatarResult = mysqli_query($link, $oldAvatarDelete) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                $oldAvatarArray = mysqli_fetch_array($oldAvatarResult);
                $oldAvatar      = $oldAvatarArray['avatar'];
                $oldAvatarPath  = $uploadFolder . $oldAvatar;
                if (file_exists($oldAvatarPath))
                    unlink($oldAvatarPath);
            }

        }
    }

// Проверка 11
        if (!$newAvatar) $newAvatar = $defaultAvatar;
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE reg_user SET avatar = '$newAvatar' WHERE login = '$login'";
        $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($link, $updateQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));

// Проверка 12
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0)
            echo 'Аватар успешно загружен';
        else return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь разберешься. Тогда старался и трудился не зря. :)
Функции которые начинаются с `mysql_` уже устарели. Их не рекомендуется использовать. Вместо этого используй:

`mysqli_connect()`, `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_fetch_array` и так далее. Смотри документацию PHP.

***UPDATE:***

*CSS* чтобы скучно небыло.

```css
form {
  displa: block;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #f9b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #036F96;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div > p {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #96292F;
}

div > img {
  max-width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #189659;
}

div > label {
  dislay: block;
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
}

div > input {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

div > input[type=submit] {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div>
        <?php if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/avatars/'.$avatar)): ?>
            <img src="<?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/avatars/'.$avatar ?>" alt="My-Avatar">
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>У вас еще нет аватарки</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="info_surname">Фамилия: </label>
        <input type="text" name="info_surname" id="info_surname" value="<?= $_SESSION['auth_surname']; ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="info_avatar">Выберите файл:</label>
        <input type="file" id="info_avatar" value="" name="fupload">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="info_edit" value="Сохранить">
    </div>

</form><!-- .Конец формы -->
```

**Форму** нельзя пихать в еще одну форму. Табличная вёрстка уже отжила свое давным давно. Создавай блочную вёрстку.

Копируешь, и запускаешь это все дело.

***Чтобы запустить:*** Копируешь код который ниже написан. Функция `redirect()` для того чтобы после отправки формы, случайно не нажал f5 и те же данные не полетели еще раз в базу.

```
$login = $_SESSION['auth_surname'];//или где ты там его берешь

function redirect() {
    $redirect = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['info_edit'])){
    updateUserAvatar($login);
    redirect(); // Перезагрузка страницы, чтобы данные с формы случайно не отправились еще раз
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46526/discussion-on-answer-by-codestealer-----).